# Mocking generic number of consecutive responses from partial mock with Mockito

Tags: mockito

I am creating a general general mock-client for testing HTTP-interactions. For this, I would like to be able to make a number of responses of the same method. 
With a normal mock, this would not be a problem:

```
when(mock.execute(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(firstResponse, otherResponses)
```

However, I am using a partial mock, where I simply want to mock method making the HTTP request, since there might not be access to a live end-point or the Internet in general for that matter in the context where the unit-tests are executed.

So I will be doing something like:

```
doReturn(response).when(spy).execute(hostCaptor.capture(), requestCaptor.capture(), contextCaptor.capture());
```

However, I would like to be able to support more than one response (not much of an "interaction"). But there are no doReturn-method, which takes a more than a single response at a time.

My first attempt on a solution was to do it iteratively:

```
Stubber stubber = null;
for (HttpResponse response : responses) {
    if (stubber == null) {
        stubber = doReturn(response);
    } else {
        stubber = stubber.doReturn(response);
    }
}
stubber.when(spy).execute(hostCaptor.capture(), requestCaptor.capture(), contextCaptor.capture());
```

This does however fail to verify ("Unfinished stubbing detected") when running the test.

So - *is there a way to achieve this with Mockito?*

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
doReturn( 1 ).doReturn( 2 ).doReturn( 3 ).when( myMock ).myMethod( any(), any(), any());
```

**Edit:**

If the values you want are in the array `myArray`, then you could also use

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;
import org.mockito.stubbing.answers.ReturnElementsOf

....

doAnswer( new ReturnsElementsOf( asList( myArray )))
   .when( myMock ).myMethod( any(), any(), any());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, but my problem is, that I don't generally know the number of responses, as it is a array (or varargs).

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I were looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found, was to use `doAnswer` to return the next response in the array.

```
Answer<HttpResponse> answer = new Answer<HttpResponse>() {

    HttpResponse[] answers = responses;
    int number = 0;

    @Override
    public HttpResponse answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        HttpResponse result = null;
        if (number <= answers.length) {
            result = answers[number]; 
            number++;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No more answers");
        }
        return result;
    }
};
doAnswer(answer).when(spy).execute(hostCaptor.capture(), requestCaptor.capture(), contextCaptor.capture());
```